# Mono for Android : Splash screen tutorial c#

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am brand new to android mono c# and am just following [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Creating_a_Splash_Screen) Mono tutorial for creating a splash screen.

I have started the tutorial several times from scratch but keep getting the same error when I try to run it through the emulator.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\duncan\My Documents\MONO Android\HelloAndroid\HelloM4A\HelloM4A\HelloM4A\AndroidManifest.xml(0,0): 
Error 1: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Splash'). (1)
```

Can anybody shed any light on a possible cause for this????

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial doesn't mention the Build Action, but the "AboutResources.txt" that I found in a tutorial solution has:

**In order to get the build system to recognize Android resources, set the build action to
"AndroidResource"**

But even after verifying that I was still getting the same error.

The gotcha I found was that the name has to be lowercase, and I suspect this is because the Android build uses resource tokens. So you don't give the actual file name but the name that resolves to the token - which at least in my case was lower case such as "splash" vs "Splash"

Answer (score 3):

Did you add Styles.xml file to the Resources/Values folder? Also, make sure that its Build Action is set to AndroidResource.

Comment: Its was the Build Action, works now. That wasnt mentioned in the tutorial! Thank you very much, you have saved me pulling out more precious hair :-).